# Errno 13 Permission denied in django-wkhtmltopdf

Tags: python, django, pdf, permissions, wkhtmltopdf

I use django-wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF documents.
I described a clear path to the django-wkhtmltopdf.

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = '/home/vagrant/envs/vagrant/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf'
```

I get the error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Permissions in the path to the django-wkhtmltopdf:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 vagrant vagrant Feb 17, 4096 7:32 wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: did you solve this problem? im getting the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) itself, and specify the path to the binary (either in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin).

Comment: I have done, and I get this:
`Command '['wkhtmltopdf', '--encoding', u'utf8', '--load-error-handling', u'ignore', '--load-media-error-handling', u'ignore', '--margin-bottom', u'0', '--margin-left', u'0', '--margin-right', u'0', '--margin-top', u'0', '--quiet', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdfIPTSFr.html', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: The specific location I needed to point to was:     /bin/xhtml2pdf

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

1. Download the file from [oficial page](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)
2. From the file you downloaded extract the /bin/wkhtmltopdf file
3. Place it somewhere at your project
4. In settings.py specify the FULL path to the binary file like:

   WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = '/home/stefanos/vEnvs/assembla/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf'