# Errno 13 Permission denied when trying to run wkhtmltopdf

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, wkhtmltopdf

> There are similar questions but my set of configuration is not the
>   same.I  downloaded the wkhtmltopdf from wkhtmltopdf.org, placed on the
>   project folder, i cant figure out why im still getting access denied.

Trying to point django to run the `wkhtmltopdf` in order to generate a pdf file.

Running NGINX with UNICORN 
Using SUPERVISOR 
Ubuntu 16

**in my unicorn_supervisor log i got:**

```
Internal Server Error: /invoice/1/pdf
    Traceback (most recent call last):emphasized text
      File "/home/instantuser/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/instantuser/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_respons                                                                                                                           e
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/home/instantuser/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_respons                                                                                                                           e
        response = response.render()
      File "/home/instantuser/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 109, in render
        self.content = self.rendered_content
      File "/home/instantuser/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/views.py", line 78, in rendered_content
        cmd_options=cmd_options
      File "/home/instantuser/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py", line 186, in render_pdf_from_temp                                                                                                                           late
        cmd_options=cmd_options)
      File "/home/instantuser/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py", line 124, in convert_to_pdf
        return wkhtmltopdf(pages=filename, **cmd_options)
      File "/home/instantuser/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py", line 110, in wkhtmltopdf
        return check_output(ck_args, **ck_kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

**The wkhtmltopdf file:**

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 instantuser instantuser 39804584 Nov 22 10:11 wkhtmltopdf
```

**Unicorn process:**

```
instant+  2949  0.1  0.5  70344 23216 ?        S    18:51   0:00 /home/instantuser/app/bin/python3 ../bin/gunicorn instanthst.wsgi:application --name instanthst --workers 3 --user=instantuser --group=instantuser --bind=unix:/home/instantuser/app/instanthst/run/gunicorn.sock --log-level=debug --log-file=-
instant+  2954  0.3  1.2 171712 51992 ?        S    18:51   0:00 /home/instantuser/app/bin/python3 ../bin/gunicorn instanthst.wsgi:application --name instanthst --workers 3 --user=instantuser --group=instantuser --bind=unix:/home/instantuser/app/instanthst/run/gunicorn.sock --log-level=debug --log-file=-
instant+  2955  0.3  1.2 171704 51936 ?        S    18:51   0:00 /home/instantuser/app/bin/python3 ../bin/gunicorn instanthst.wsgi:application --name instanthst --workers 3 --user=instantuser --group=instantuser --bind=unix:/home/instantuser/app/instanthst/run/gunicorn.sock --log-level=debug --log-file=-
instant+  2957  0.3  1.2 171568 51960 ?        S    18:51   0:00 /home/instantuser/app/bin/python3 ../bin/gunicorn instanthst.wsgi:application --name instanthst --workers 3 --user=instantuser --group=instantuser --bind=unix:/home/instantuser/app/instanthst/run/gunicorn.sock --log-level=debug --log-file=-
ubuntu    2970  0.0  0.0  12944   964 pts/0    S+   18:53   0:00 grep --color=auto unicorn
```

**NGINX Process**

```
root      3006  0.0  0.0 125112  1460 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  3007  0.0  0.0 125436  3108 ?        S    18:55   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  3008  0.0  0.1 125712  5060 ?        S    18:55   0:00 nginx: worker process
ubuntu    3104  0.0  0.0  12944   940 pts/0    S+   19:09   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Why am I getting access denied since the wkhtmltopdf file owner is the same running unicorn?

I'm able to run the command in the terminal but python cant run it. why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errno 13 Permission denied in djnago-wkhtmltopdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580691/errno-13-permission-denied-in-djnago-wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: It is not enough to have execute permissions on the file to actually run it. You also need permissions to list all of its parent folders. Since you placed wkhtmltopdf into the project folder, I assume this is the most likely issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by creating an shell script file to call the wkhtmltopdf.

**wkhtmltopdf.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1024x768x16" wkhtmltopdf $*
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score -2):

Just use
    sudo su
or
    sudo command
That will run it as superuser and bypass all permissions. I the case that you Don't have access to superuser, I am not sure. This sometimes happens to me when I am trying to run something that is not supposed to be ran. Though I use ubuntu 14.04, so I don't understand this as well as others might.